# Django: How to display database results based on form input selection?

Tags: python, django, database, forms, filter

I am trying to query the database to display results from the form. Once I select the form drop-down fields for my wanted query e.g. Ford C-Max 2019 1.2 Petrol 1500 , from which I coded for now to display results (regardless of Make & Model as I only have one atm) , then instead of showing me the table with matched results I get the full table with all results instead of the query I want.

Portion of what I get after submitting the form (includes results I want filtered out):

```
year    liter fuel  mileage average entered

2019    1.2 Petrol  1500    12075   April 8, 2020, 11:11 p.m.
0                   None    13780   April 14, 2020, 5:25 p.m.
2018    1.6 Diesel  5000    15000   April 15, 2020, 2:23 p.m.
```

What I want to get based on selecting 2019 1.2 Petrol etc. in the form:

```
2019    1.2 Petrol  1500    12075   April 8, 2020, 11:11 p.m.
```

My code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Average, Query
from .forms import QueryForm

class QueryMakeModel(FormView):
        template_name = 'QueryMakeModel.html'
        success_url = '/data/'
        form_class = QueryForm

        def form_valid(self, form):
            return HttpResponse("Sweet.")

def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        FormSite = QueryForm(request.POST)
        if FormSite.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        FormSite = QueryForm()

    return render(request, 'app/QueryMakeModel.html', {'FormSite': FormSite})

def data(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query= request.GET.get('q')

        if query is not None:
            lookups= Q(mileage__icontains= query) & Q(fuel__icontains=query) & Q(liter__icontains=query) 
            & Q(year__icontains=query)

            query_results= Average.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()

            context = { 
                'query': query,
                'query_results': query_results,
            }

            return render(request, 'app/db.html', context)
```

db.html (Data display page)

```
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Liter</th>
                <th>Fuel</th>
                <th>Mileage</th>
                <th>Average</th>
                <th>Entered</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for Average in query_results %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0">{{ Average.year }}</td>
                <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0">{{ Average.liter }}</td>
                <td>{{ Average.fuel }}</td>
                <td>{{ Average.mileage }}</td>
                <td>{{ Average.average }}</td>
                <td>{{ Average.entered }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>
</body>
```

QueryMakeModel.html (Main Query Form Page)

```
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <h2>DoneDeal Average Price Checker</h2>
    <p></p>
    <p>Please fill the details below:</p>

    <form action="/data/" method="get">{% csrf_token %}

        {{  FormSite.as_p }}

    <button type="submit" name ='q'>
        <i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> Query
    </button>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

models.py

```
class Query(models.Model):  
    MAKE    = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices=MAKES)
    MODEL   = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices=MODELS)
    YEAR    = models.IntegerField(max_length = 4, choices=YEARS)
    LITER   = models.CharField(max_length = 3, choices=LITERS)
    FUEL    = models.CharField(max_length = 6, choices=FUELS)
    MILEAGE = models.IntegerField(max_length = 10, choices=MILEAGES)

class Average(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ford_cmax'

    average = models.IntegerField(max_length = 6)
    entered = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True)
    year    = models.IntegerField(max_length = 4)
    liter   = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
    fuel    = models.CharField(max_length = 6)
    mileage = models.IntegerField(max_length = 10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app import views
from django.conf.urls import include, url 
from app.views import QueryMakeModel

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='Index'),
    path('data/', views.data, name='Data')
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms  
from .models import Query, Average, YEARS, MAKES, MODELS, LITERS, FUELS, MILEAGES, DATES
import django_filters

class QueryForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    error_css_class = 'error'

    YEAR = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEARS )
    MAKE = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MAKES, required=True )
    MODEL = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MODELS, required=True )
    LITER = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LITERS )
    FUEL = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FUELS )
    MILEAGE = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MILEAGES )
    #ENTERED = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DATES )

    class Meta:
        model = Query
        fields = ['MAKE', 'MODEL', 'YEAR', 'LITER', 'FUEL', 'MILEAGE']
```

Comment: are you sure your `lookup` is correct ?

Comment: did you check what you have in `query` ? `get("q")` should gives you value only from `<button name="q">`, but not from other fields. Other fields has other name (not `q`) and they need to get then using its names.

Comment: @furas I am not sure, all i know is that if I hard code the value into it then it works, for example: ``` Q(fuel__icontains='Petrol' ``` works but I want the variable to pick up from the form.

Comment: first see what you have in `query` which you use in `mileage__icontains= query` (etc.). You may have empty string or something which matchs to all values in database - so it gives full tables

Comment: BTW: `get("q")` doesn't meen to get values from fields in form but only value assigned to `<button>` which has `name="q"`. You may need `FormSite = QueryForm(request.POST)` and `if FormSite.is_valid():` or create `<input name="q">` to get value

Comment: @furas okay I am starting to understand what you mean. You are probably right. Sorry, I am a complete noob to Django and Python ^^. That's what I am trying to figure out, where do I assign what you said? Unsure what you mean by create <input name = "q"> to get a value. Perhaps I need help with how to draw the form values into the lookup.

Comment: it seems you have to first learn HTML and HTTP (how web browser comunicates with server)

Comment: `<input name = "q">` creates (in form) fields where you can write text and when you use `get("g")` then you get text only from this field. But you have to change name in `<button>` (or even remove name from button) because now `get("g")` try to get value from button which has no value. Every field in form should have own unique name and you use `get("unique name")` to get value only from this one field.

Comment: @furas Okay I understand. But where do I put that <input name = "q" inside the form? In forms.py I don't see where to include it as it's not a HTML but ModelForm.

Comment: it seems you need `<input name="q">` instead of `{{  FormSite.as_p }}` . it will display only one field for text - but later you use `query= request.GET.get('q')` to get only one value. And you don't use values from `{{  FormSite.as_p }}` to filter data.